# Django Flot e javascript

Tags: javascript, django, flot

I would like to do some graphics in my django application. I'm using Flot. I am a newbee with regard to javascript and I do not know how to pass parameters in my situation. This is my code:

view.py

```
data = []
query = tab_data.objects.all()
for row in query:
    data.append([str(row.time), str(row.rate)])
data = json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
...
return render_to_response('index.html', {'data' : data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
<div class="portlet-body">
       <div id="site_statistics_loading">
           <img src="/static/assets/img/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
       </div>
       <div id="site_statistics_content" class="hide">
            <div id="site_statistics" class="chart"></div>
       </div>
</div>
...
... # at the end of the page I have this
Index.initCharts(); // init index page's custom scripts
```

Index.js

```
initCharts: function () {
   if (!jQuery.plot) {
            return;
        }
    var data = []; # Here I would like my data.
```

How do I pass the data to file index.js? Sorry for the trivial question but I do not know how to do ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A series can either be raw data or an object with properties. The raw
data format is an array of points:

[ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]

E.g. (in your case)

```
data=   [[1, 3], [2, 14.01], [3.5, 3.14]];   //You can build this string in the html generated and/or add it with jquery/ajax callback function.
```

If you want some more sophisticated (with styles in the lines and dots for example you have to build basically building the "option" parameter.

```
$.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

**placeholder** is the div container which will contain the graph.
**data** is the data in the format described before. (Take care of the String building)
**options** is the option of the graph (lines, series, style, dots).

You will find more information here http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt

Comment: The question is another. I do not understand how to pass {{data}} to the file index.js. I to do this: Index.initCharts("{{data}}"); I do not know how to fill the variable var data = []; in my index.js

Comment: In the index.js you have to do it with Ajax, but you can do in the HTML file like this (for one time only loading):<script type="text/javascript">data = {% generate your data in the server side here %}; </script>